# Handling googleapi client errors

Tags: python, exception, google-calendar-api

I am reading and creating the calendar event for set of emails through Google calendar API. Now If I give one email id is wrong it's throwing an error .

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.goo
gleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/xxx%40gmail.com/events?timeMin=2019-1
2-18T00%3A00%3A00%2B05%3A30&maxResults=240&timeMax=2019-12-18T23%3A59%3A00%2B05%
3A30&singleEvents=true&orderBy=startTime&alt=json returned "Not Found">
```

I can understand there is wrong in the email and I am getting this error. But I want to handle this exception,like if my email is wrong also it should skip the wrong email and it should go further and display the proper result.

What I tried is

```
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

def my_funtion():

        try:
            ----
            -----
        except HttpError as err:
            print("The exception is",err)
        finally:
            return "I am returning whatever i get it from try
```

Is it correct try catch block?
for the above code I am getting the same googleclientapi error,It's not going inside the excpet block

What I expect here is
It should go to the try block,if one of the email id is wrong,it should skip the email id and it should return the result of whatever is getting fetched from the try block.
I can say it should omit the apiclient but and return the result.

````
#for calendar_id in calendar_ids:    
    eventsResult = service.events().list(calendarId=["a@gmail.com","b@gmail.com","c@gmail.com"],timeMin=start_date,timeMax=end_date,singleEvents=True,orderBy='startTime').execute()
    events = eventsResult.get('items', [])
    if not events:
        print('No upcoming events found.')
    print(events)
    while True:
        for event in events.get('items', []):
            print(event['summary'])
        page_token = events.get('nextPageToken') #check if any event present in next page of the calendar
        if page_token:
            events = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', pageToken=page_token).execute()
        else:
            break

    for calendar_id in calendar_ids:
        count = 0
        print('\n----%s:\n' % calendar_id)
        try:
            eventsResult = service.events().list(
                calendarId=calendar_id,
                timeMin=start_date,
                timeMax=end_date,
                singleEvents=True,
                orderBy='startTime').execute()
            events = eventsResult.get('items', [])
            if not events:
                print('No upcoming events found.')
            for event in events:
                if 'summary' in event:
                    if 'PTO' in event['summary']:
                        count += 1
                        start = event['start'].get(
                            'dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
                        print(start, event['summary'])
        except exception as err:
            print("I am executing",err)
        finally:
            print('Total days off for %s is %d' % (calendar_id, count))```
````

Comment: The exception you are catching is `HttpError`, is it same what googleclientapi is raising? If no and you don't know the exact exception name then first put one more exception block with generic exception `Exception` below the current except block and then try

Comment: I knew it's a Http Error.But anyhow I tried using Exceptions also ,it's not going inside the except block.Is it correct way to handle the exception?I am new to Python

Comment: Exceptions or Exception? It should be `except Exception as ex:`

Comment: I used exception only

Comment: Can you paste the whole code?

Comment: I have added it

Comment: The keyword for a "general" exception in python is `Exception`. If you write it in lowercase it will not catch as an `Exception`. If you want you can take a look at the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) that should clarify the syntax for `try` and `except` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer for this post. I have used 'pass' in exception block and it worked well.Thanks

Comment: Could you provide the code that solved your problem to help people that could have the same problem that you.